# Каково количество возможных ключей в AES-128?

Tags: aes

В интернете есть информация о количестве возможных ключей, это около 340 ундециллионов, но меня интересует другое: как получено это число? То есть количество ключей определяется по формуле m^n, где m - длина используемого алфавита, n - длина ключа. Длина ключа известна - 16, количество возможных ключей известно - 340 ундециллионов, но какова длина используемого алфавита? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну так найдите корень и будет вам m)) `(34 * 10 ** 37) ** (1 / 16) = 256`

Comment: Спасибо, сам не додумался

Comment: А если в обратную сторону, то "_Длина ключа известна - 16_". 16 чего ? правильно, байт, а байт он длиной 8 бит, 2^8 = 256  Ну или "А почему AES именно 128" он 128 бит это и есть длина ключа в битах. так что просто 2 ^ 128 (ибо алфавит в двоичной системе длиной 2)

Comment: Т.е. вы ни разу не встретили запись 2^128? На что как бы намекает число 128 в названии шифра